# Laravel controller does not get correct parameter from route definition, and enters in the wrong controller function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have this route defined:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/{class}/{function}/', [OldBackendController::class, 'apiV1']);
```

If I do this request:

```
POST /api/v2_1/wishlist/archive
```

Laravel enters int the `OldBackendController`, and the value of `$class` variable (in the controller), is this:

```
api/v2_1/wishlist
```

Why? It shouldn't enter in the controller, cause the request does not contains 2 variables, but 4.

The strange thing is if in the controller I print `$request->segments()` value, I get all 4 segment:

```
Array
(
    [0] => api
    [1] => v2_1
    [2] => wishlist
    [3] => archive
)
```

Comment: Your route has both dyanmic parameters so your route position is very important here. This route should be at last of the route file.

Comment: still the route defines 2 variables and not 4

Comment: what webserver are you using? how did you setup pretty urls / url rewriting?

Comment: As you mentioned in a comment on the answer below, [according to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes) the `/` should be excluded automatically from any route parameter.  Just to be clear, what does your `apiV1()` method signature look like?  It is unlikely, but `$class` and `$function` might be reserved words, have you tried using other param names?

Comment: @Don'tPanic `public function apiV1(Request $request, string $class, string $function,)`

Comment: Is the route defined in `routes/api.php`?  Are there any prefixes or groups for it?  Is it possible another route is matching and clashing, does anything change if you temporarily remove every other route, in both `api.php` and `web.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You route contain two variables but as you saw, it will try to interpret any uri to those variable as possible as it can and you end up having the uri `/api/v2_1/wishlist/archive` broken down to two variables `api/v2_1/wishlist` and `archive`.

What you need is to tell the route to not match the character `/` inside the variables

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{class}/{function}', [OldBackendController::class, 'apiV1'])
    ->where('class', '[A-Za-z]+')->where('function', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

You can adapt the regex if your function contain `_` or `-` or numeric characters.

For more information check the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

note: In all cases, you should put this route at the end of your route file as it will match with anything that has two uri segments and give you a headache in the future.

Comment: Got it. My concern is why I should exclude the character / with reg exp. It should be excluded automatically by Laravel.

Comment: @GiacomoM that is the beauty of "Dynamic" property. It will match anything there. Yeah, it isn't very clear initially and the best practice is never to have this type of route. It will cause lots of issues this route will also catch your 404 routes and will call your controller.

Comment: @AnujShrestha It certainly looks like that is what is happening, but no, they should not match anything there, as OP already pointed out.  [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes): "*The Laravel routing component allows all characters except / to be present within route parameter values. You must explicitly allow / to be part of your placeholder using a where condition regular expression*".

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it and Laravel is handling it properly without the use of regex too. it is not going there if the route path has more or less than 2. No idea why it is failing for OP.